# Using embedding for convolutional features and low dimensional output space

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

say I have some convolutional features that I wanna pass through an encoder-decoder model and map pixels to a certain vocabulary. In the context of language translation models I saw that the best practice is to map your vocabulary to a lower dimensional space using Embedding layers (I am using PyTorch). Now, in my case the vocabularies are **1. extracted features through convolutions** and **2. a set of characters with cardinality of 30**. My questions are:

1. do I need to use embeddings for the first vocabulary, although the these features are continuous and not one hot encodings with respect to a vocabulary's dimensionality?
2. do I need to use embeddings for the output vocabulary which is low-dimensional?

I have to mention that I trained a model without embeddings to the encoder input (conv features) and mapped the decoder input to a higher dimension (50) and got fairly good results, but I just want to see if my method is correct or there are better practices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are your base units, word-boundary identified words or arbitrary-length 30 character strings?

Comment: they're just characters, like 'a', '$', '#', etc.

Comment: When I've used embeddings (glove, word2vec etc) I've always had to decompose my text into a word-level vocabulary before converting to an embedded vector. One way of getting dimensionality reduction, after scraping say the top 100,000+ most common vocabulary points, is to then cluster those results to find a reduced vocabulary of say 10000 archetypical reference points. You end up with a M-1 mapping of synonyms from the larger space onto a smaller one. It can look a bit unusual sometimes, but can work out reasonably well and work as an alternative to stemming and other typical NLP processing.